# How to allow gRPC Channel in Java to use multiple connections?

Tags: grpc, http2, grpc-java

Javadoc for *io.grpc.Channel* class mentions that,

> A channel is free to have zero or many actual connections to the
> endpoint based on configuration, load, etc

My question is, how do I enable this configuration, which allows gRPC's channel to open multiple actual connections when needed ?

Update:
According to [this Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/performance?view=aspnetcore-5.0#connection-concurrency), only one TCP connection is made !

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior, no configuration needed. See https://grpc.io/docs/guides/performance/ for a few tips on gRPC best practices, there's a short blurb in there about Channels and HTTP/2 connection limits.

Comment: This document itself seems bit confusing to me ! It mentions both things
 
- Each gRPC channel uses 0 or more HTTP/2 connections 

- Use a pool of gRPC channels to distribute RPCs over multiple connections

Comment: so back to same question, who manages these multiple connections ! If we, then do I have to use some RoundRobin fashion to send RPC to channel, or if gRPC, then how ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the feature(or configuration) is readily available in grpc-java or grpc-go client. However, you can explore grpc-dotnet client, I think they found a [workaround](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/performance?view=aspnetcore-5.0#connection-concurrency)(which even they don't recommend using).

> who manages these multiple connections

In grpc-java, the channel itself manages the HTTP/2 connections. We don't have access to these connections(if we want to configure them).

There may be a possible workaround to implement the same by - "creating multiple channels". See [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/21386#issuecomment-564742173)